# Passing Trivy results to harbor

Tags: harbor, trivy

Before pushing an image into Harbor, I'm running a Trivy scan. Instead of having Trivy scan images again within harbor, I'm looking for a way to pass the JSON results from Trivy into harbor.

`trivy image hello_docker_compose_web --output results.json -f json`

Is there a way to have Harbor consume this `results.json` along with the image being pushed to harbor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible, to upload scan results from external Trivy back to Harbor.
The only option is to run the scan again within Harbor.